# Populate data to tables as per daterange

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle:

```
select * from leave;

--LEAVE_DTL_ID is auto incremented

LEAVE_DTL_ID   STAFF_ID START_DT  END_DT                                        
------------ ---------- --------- ---------                                     
          49        654 21-JAN-19 23-JAN-19                                     
         186         55 02-MAY-19 06-MAY-19                                     
         280        354 09-JUN-19 14-JUN-19
```

I want to combine the `START_DT` and `END_DT` columns to a single column named 'DATES' as per the corresponding date range.

Eg: take `LEAVE_DTL_ID = 186` it has `START_DT = '02-MAY-19'` and `END_DT = '06-MAY-19'`.

I want to populate the data as

```
LEAVE_DTL_ID   STAFF_ID DATES                                                   
------------ ---------- ---------                                               
         186         55 02-MAY-19                                               
         187         55 03-MAY-19                                               
         188         55 04-MAY-19                                               
         189         55 05-MAY-19                                               
         190         55 06-MAY-19
```

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Are you exclusively looking for a query ? or are you okay with procedures too ?

Comment: @DockYard : Both will helpfull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SQL> with leave (leave_dtl_id, staff_id, start_dt, end_dt) as
  2    (select  49, 654, date '2019-01-21', date '2019-01-23' from dual union all
  3     select 186,  55, date '2019-05-02', date '2019-05-06' from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    (leave_dtl_id + column_value - 1) as leave_dtl_id,
  7    staff_id,
  8    (start_dt + column_value - 1) as dates
  9  from leave cross join
 10       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                           connect by level <= end_dt - start_dt + 1
 12                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13  order by staff_id, dates;

LEAVE_DTL_ID   STAFF_ID DATES
------------ ---------- --------
         186         55 02.05.19
         187         55 03.05.19
         188         55 04.05.19
         189         55 05.05.19
         190         55 06.05.19
          49        654 21.01.19
          50        654 22.01.19
          51        654 23.01.19

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Nice - I like the part with joining the multiset to avoid duplicates...

Comment: Right; it behaves better than DISTINCT, @Radagast

Comment: Yeah especially when you want to process the data further with join or filter in application it's nice to have this approach, so that oracle could use indices to filter etc.

Comment: I personally prefere `cross join` instead of `join ... on 1=1`. I don't know if it makes really a difference but i have the feeling that 1=1 is still a condition that has to be evaluated and therefore costs little additional time to `cross join`.

Comment: @Littlefoot : Thank you for your valuable answer  for the Question.It saved a lot of time for me.